# UITextView will get down when i click textField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitextview

I have a `TextView` & a `textFile` in My `ViewController` 
When I click my `textFile` , my iPhone doesn't have any problem
but my simulator will get down ,
and ,if i click "Tab" it will get down again,
It was over I set navigation controller,
does anyone know what happened?

Just like this, the black area is my question

[image]

Answer (score 0):

could you post the piece of code where the simulator crash or ‘goes down’?

Strange that it doesn’t work on simulator and works on device, normally the other way around :p. You could reset contents of the simulator(Simulator -> Reset Content….) or delete and rebuild the app.

Answer (score 0):

I find my question is in Simulator's keyboard..

I uncheck the `hardware > Keyboard > Connect Haredware Keyboard` 
then it's no problem 
It was because this

```
-(void) keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *) notification {
    NSValue * value = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGFloat keyboardHeight = [value CGRectValue].size.height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^
      {
         CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
         frame.origin.y -= keyboardHeight;
         self.view.frame = frame;
      }
     ];
}
```